# Get data from a form and send it as a HTTP Request

Tags: php, html, http

Okay so, i'm pretty sure this is really easy to do but i just cant make it work.
I dont know how to actually google or form this question so ill try to explain as much as i can.
I'm trying to use an API from a page and the documentation says that a HTTP request should look like this:

```
https://example.com/dashboard/api
?to={PHONE NUMBER}&from={SENDER ID}&message={TEXT}
&email={YOUR EMAIL}&api_secret={API SECRET}
```

My goal is to use these parameters and build a basic html form where it asks for the input of 3 different parameters.

"to", "from" and "message"

And then sumbit that information from the form to the http request.

In the documentation they have an example of a JSON response that looks like this:

```
{
  "to":"4928400837",
  "status":"0",
  "status_info":"Message sent",
  "credits_spent":"1",
  "remaining_credits":43,
  "id":"username123"
}
```

Not sure if it helps with anything but thats about it. I have no idea how to begin with this.
Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you trying to do this on the server (since you've tagged this as PHP)?

Comment: Assuming yes: http://docs.php.net/manual/da/httprequest.send.php

Comment: Trying to do this on my web server.

Comment: @Alex: What's the question? How to make a form? How to send a form? How to read values from URL?

Comment: Sorry for not clarifying, my question or need is: I need to make a form that takes these parameters from the user and sends them as a friend request.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a form using HTML, which you serve to the client, and which sends a POST request on submission to your PHP back-end.

A simple example might look something like this:

```
<div class="body"> 
    <form method="post" action="index.php">
        <div id="form"> 
            <div class="formInput"> 
                <label>To: 
                <input type="text" name="to" id="to" /> 
                </label> 
            </div> 
            <div class="formInput"> 
                <label>From: 
                <input type="text" name="from" id="from" /> 
                </label> 
            </div> 
            <div class="formInput"> 
                <label>Message: 
                <input type="text" name="message" id="message" /> 
                </label> 
            </div>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" /> 
            <input type="reset" value="Clear Form" /> 
        </div> 
    </form>
```

Your PHP code can then access all of the form variables in the `$_POST` array to send the GET request to the API using the `$_POST` parameters from your user form.

```
<?php
$url = 'https://example.com/dashboard/api';
$r = new HttpRequest($url, HttpRequest::METH_GET);
// build a URL query string with the parameters passed from the form
$r->addQueryData(array('to' => $_POST['to'],
                       'from' => $_POST['from'],
                       'email' => $email,
                       'api_secret' => $api_secret));
// send the HTTP GET request and display the JSON response
try {
    $r->send();
    if ($r->getResponseCode() == 200) {
        echo $r->getResponseBody();
    }
} catch (HttpException $ex) {
    echo $ex;
}
?>
```

In this simplistic example, your `index.php` would effectively translate the user's POST data into GET data when you hit the API. Realistically, you could then redirect the user to a different page that you pass the API's JSON response, so that it can be formatted. I wasn't sure if you intended `$email` to be part of the user form, and I'm assuming the API secret must be stored server-side somewhere.

Comment: This is exactly what i wanted sadly i get an error when i press sumbit, example.com is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500

Comment: The error i'm getting is "PHP Fatal error:  Class 'HttpRequest' not found" any chance its from the php version?